# Preg_replace 'shortcodes' in php

Tags: php

I've got a string containing [center] (with the square brackets) which then needs to be replaced with another string. I'm sure there must be a way of doing this using preg_replace but cant get it working

Comment: You don't need regexes, just `str_replace`

Comment: Show some code pls

Answer (score 0):

a regular expression would be overkill fo such a task, use [str_replace](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php)

```
$str="I've got a string containing [center] (with the square brackets)";

$new_str=str_replace('[center]','[left]',$str);

echo $new_str; //I've got a string containing [left] (with the square brackets)
```

Answer (score 0):

Do like this

```
    <?php

$a="abc [dfh]124[center]";

$b=preg_replace ('/\[(.*?)\]/s','[replace]', $a);   // this will replace the string with in the square brackets

echo $b;

?>
```

Hope this will help you

Thank you.